# What's the difference between Reactive Value and Reactive Expression?

Tags: r, shiny

In [Shiny tutorial](http://rstudio.github.io/shiny/tutorial/#reactivity-overview), there is an example:

```
fib <- function(n) ifelse(n<3, 1, fib(n-1)+fib(n-2))

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  currentFib         <- reactive({ fib(as.numeric(input$n)) })

  output$nthValue    <- renderText({ currentFib() })
  output$nthValueInv <- renderText({ 1 / currentFib() })
})
```

I don't get how `reactive` caches the values. Does it internally do something like `return(function() cachedValue)`?
Now I am wondering if I can do this?

```
fib <- function(n) ifelse(n<3, 1, fib(n-1)+fib(n-2))

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  currentFib         <- reactiveValues({ fib(as.numeric(input$n)) })

  output$nthValue    <- renderText({ currentFib })
  output$nthValueInv <- renderText({ 1 / currentFib })
})
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Using 
`currentFib         <- reactiveValues({ fib(as.numeric(input$n)) })` will not work in this context.
You will get an error saying that you are accessing reactive values outside of the "reactive context."

However, if you wrap it inside a function call instead, it will work:

`currentFib         <- function(){ fib(as.numeric(input$n)) }`

This works because now the function call is inside a reactive context.

The **key difference** is the distinction they make in the [Shiny documentation](http://rstudio.github.io/shiny/tutorial/#reactivity-overview), between reactive "sources" and "conductors." In that terminology, `reactive({...})` is a **conductor**, but `reactiveValues` can only be a **source**.

- Here's how I think of `reactiveValues` - as a way to extend `input` which gets specified in *UI.R.* Sometimes, the slots in `input` are not enough, and we want *derived values* based on those input slots. In other words, it is a way to extend the list of `input` slots for future reactive computations.
- `Reactive()` does what you say -- it returns the value, *after re-running the expression each time any reactive Value changes.* If you look at the source code for `reactive` you can see it:
  The last line is that cached value that is being returned: `Observable$new(fun, label)$getValue` where 'fun' is the expression that was sent in the call to `reactive.`