# Storing reactive data in shiny from SQL

Tags: r, shiny, rmysql

This is a follow up from this question:

[Acessing SQL database using shiny with reactive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31446500/acessing-sql-database-using-shiny-with-reactive-query)

I am trying to build a data frame from data fetched from an SQL database using a shiny app. Currently i am able to query the database and return one set of data. Now I would like to save that data to a data frame and then add more data from subsequent queries. Here is my code:

UI

```
library(markdown)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Generic grapher"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      numericInput("wafer", label = h3("Select wafer ID:"), value = NULL),

      actionButton("do", "An action button")
      ),

      mainPanel(
        verbatimTextOutput("value"), verbatimTextOutput("que"), dataTableOutput(outputId="pos")
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Server:

```
library(RMySQL)
library(DBI)
library(sqldf)

con = dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), dbname="xx", username="pete", password="xx", host="xx", port=3306)
query <-  function(...) dbGetQuery(con, ...) 

wq = data.frame()

shinyServer(function(input, output){

  d <- eventReactive(input$do, { input$wafer })

  output$value <- renderPrint({ d() }) 

  a <- reactive({ paste("Select id from wafer where wafer_id=",d(), sep="") })

  output$que <- renderPrint({ a() }) 

  wq <- reactive({  query( a() ) })

  output$pos <- renderDataTable({ wq() })  

  })
```

Now I am trying to use the information from these two answers to store the data from each search I do in a data frame:

[Add values to a reactive table in shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236944/add-values-to-a-reactive-table-in-shiny)

[What's the difference between Reactive Value and Reactive Expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18324397/whats-the-difference-between-reactive-value-and-reactive-expression)

New Server:

```
library(RMySQL)
library(DBI)
library(sqldf)

con = dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), dbname="xx", username="pete", password="xx", host="xx", port=3306)
query <-  function(...) dbGetQuery(con, ...) 

wq = data.frame()

shinyServer(function(input, output){

  values <- reactiveValues()
  values$df <- data.frame()

  d <- eventReactive(input$do, { input$wafer })

  output$value <- renderPrint({ d() }) 

  a <- reactive({ paste("Select id from wafer where wafer_id=",d(), sep="") })

  output$que <- renderPrint({ a() }) 

  wq <- reactive({  query( a() ) })

  values$df <- reactive({ rbind(values$df, wq() )   }) 

  output$pos <- renderDataTable({ values$df })  

  })
```

However, when I do this the data table never renders within my app. I dont have an error message. Any ideas where Im going wrong? Any help appreciated!

Comment: I have just published an example app that does this: https://github.com/MarkEdmondson1234/ga-dashboard-demo

Comment: check out the server.r for "eventTable" and "eventData", and the MySQL functions in functions.r such as loadData()

Comment: Thanks MarkeD, I will have a go a replicating. That app is very cool! I will learn a lot from it and hopefully implement some of the functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think changing

```
values$df <- reactive({ rbind(values$df, wq() )   })
```

in your new `server.R` to

```
observe({
  values$df <- rbind(isolate(values$df), wq())
})
```

might fix your problem.

**EDIT:** Here's a working example using a local connection:

```
library(markdown)
library(RMySQL)
library(DBI)
library(sqldf)

con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
dbWriteTable(con, "mtcars", mtcars)
query <-  function(...) dbGetQuery(con, ...) 

wq = data.frame()

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Generic grapher"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      numericInput("wafer", label = h3("Select number of cylinders:"),
                   value = NULL),

      actionButton("do", "An action button")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("value"),
      verbatimTextOutput("que"),
      verbatimTextOutput("wq_print"),
      dataTableOutput(outputId="pos")
    )
  )
)
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output){

  values <- reactiveValues()
  values$df <- data.frame()

  d <- eventReactive(input$do, { input$wafer })

  output$value <- renderPrint({ d() }) 

  a <- reactive({ paste("SELECT * FROM mtcars WHERE cyl = ", d(), sep="") })

  output$que <- renderPrint({ a() }) 

  observe({
    if (!is.null(d())) {
      wq <- reactive({  query( a() ) })

      output$wq_print <- renderPrint({ print(str(wq())) })

      values$df <- rbind(isolate(values$df), wq())
    }
  })

  output$pos <- renderDataTable({ values$df })  

})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The relevant changes to your original code are the `!is.null(d())` condition for handling the initial `NULL` value of `d()`, and using `values$df <- rbind(isolate(values$df), wq())` inside an observer. Hope this helps with fixing your code!

Comment: Thanks for you reply. On trying I get the error: observe({
    values$df <- rbind(values$df, wq())
})
ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer

Comment: ah hang on didnt see isolate

Comment: ah still same error with isolate: observe({
    values$df <- rbind(isolate(values$df), wq())
})
ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer

Comment: Is the `dbConnect` call you show in the code the correct one to use? When I try reproducing your example, I get an error connecting to the database followed by `ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer`.

Comment: er dam, i was supposed to leave out the details :-s ! but yes that is correct...ok need to edit that ASAP !

Comment: sorry about that. Anyway yes, thats the same error message I get. The connection works for other things and was working before i changed the code.

Comment: yes ive just checked, the dbConnect works without the updated code to observe values$df

Comment: Heh, fair enough! I played around using a local connection instead. I think the problem is that on launch the value of `d()` will be `NULL`. I'll edit a working example in to my answer in a bit.

Comment: @Pete Added a working example, hope you can pick up the relevant changes to your code and see if they help.

Comment: Thank you so much. Also, thanks for being sensitive to my blunder of putting SQL login online!! Brilliant.