# Data frame won't update using observeEvent in Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I am a novice programmer, please excuse if I am not clear or missing relevant information. I have a shiny app written that imports a dataframe from another set of code. I would like to update that dataframe with user input in the app. I have gotten this to work where I upload the dataframe as a reactive variable using the code below:

DATA

```
current.shiny <- data.frame("Task" = as.character(c("Task 1", "Task 2", "Task 3")), "Completed" = as.character(c("Yes", "NO", "Yes")),"Date.Completed" = as.Date(c("2020-10-19","2020-10-20", "2020-10-21")))
```

UI

```
ui<- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Week of 11.02.2020"),
  
  # Sidebar with reactive inputs
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "task.choice", label = "Task",
                  choices =  c(as.list(current.shiny$Task))),
      selectInput(inputId = "completed", label = "Completed?",
                  choices = c("Yes" = "Yes", "No" = "No")),
      dateInput(inputId = "date.completed", label ="Date Completed"),
      actionButton("update","Update Sheet")
      
    ),
    
    # a table of reactive outputs
    mainPanel(
      mainPanel(
        
        #DT::dataTableOutput("dt_table", width = 500)
        
      )
    )
  ),
  # column(12,
  #        DT::dataTableOutput("data", width = "100%")),
  column(12,
         DT::dataTableOutput("xchange", width = "100%"))
)
```

SERVER 1

```
server <- function(input, output) {
# # Re-read data for any changes, write to csv new changes, ignore startup
 observeEvent(input$update,{
   test.data<-current.shiny
   test.data$Completed[test.data$Task == input$task.choice]<-as.character(input$completed)
   ignoreInit=T
 })

 # #Reactive variable xchange that updates the values of data
 xchange<-reactive({
   test.data<-current.shiny
   test.data$Completed[test.data$Task == input$task.choice]<-as.character(input$completed)
   test.data$Date.Completed[test.data$Task == input$task.choice]<-as.Date(input$date.completed)
   test.data
 })

 #Display the most recent file, with the most recent changes
 output$xchange <- renderDataTable({
   datatable(xchange(), options = list(dom = "t"))
 })
}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

This works to a degree. However, it is over-reactive in that I need it to only update the table once a button is pressed. The observeEvent function in the above code doesn't seem to do anything (it was mostly copy/pasted from another stack overflow thread). I've tried to set this up below, but I cannot get it to run.

SERVER 2

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  rxframe <- reactiveVal(
    as.data.frame(current.shiny)
  )
  observeEvent(input$update, {
    rxframe$Completed[rxframe$Task == input$task.choice]<-as.character(input$completed)
  })
  output$xchange <- shiny::renderTable( rxframe() )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Can anyone see some way that I am calling the observeEvent incorrectly that is causing it to not function properly? Any insight would be greatly appreciated, I've been stuck on this for some time.

Comment: Please provide us with a minimal app (ui / server / example data) so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @ismirsehregal I have updated the post to include that relevant information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code directly reacted to every change because you are using `reactive`.

If you want to delay the reaction you can use `observeEvent` along with `reactiveValues` or `eventReactive`.

Here is an example using `reactiveVal` and `observeEvent`:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

current.shiny <- data.frame(
    "Task" = as.character(c("Task 1", "Task 2", "Task 3")),
    "Completed" = as.character(c("Yes", "NO", "Yes")),
    "Date.Completed" = as.Date(c("2020-10-19", "2020-10-20", "2020-10-21"))
  )

ui <- fluidPage(
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Week of 11.02.2020"),
  
  # Sidebar with reactive inputs
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(
        inputId = "task.choice",
        label = "Task",
        choices =  c(as.list(current.shiny$Task))
      ),
      selectInput(
        inputId = "completed",
        label = "Completed?",
        choices = c("Yes" = "Yes", "No" = "No")
      ),
      dateInput(inputId = "date.completed", label = "Date Completed"),
      actionButton("update", "Update Sheet")
    ),
    mainPanel(column(
      12,
      DT::dataTableOutput("xchangeOut", width = "100%")
    ))
  ))

server <- function(input, output) {
  xchange <- reactiveVal(current.shiny)
  observeEvent(input$update, {
    test.data <- xchange()
    test.data$Completed[test.data$Task == input$task.choice] <-input$completed
    test.data$Date.Completed[test.data$Task == input$task.choice] <- input$date.completed
    xchange(test.data)
    # write.csv
  })
  
  #Display the most recent file, with the most recent changes
  output$xchangeOut <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(xchange(), options = list(dom = "t"))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Just my personal opinion: I prefer using `eventReactive` in this case, because then you can directly infer the intended behaviour (as this is made especially for this case); but with `observeEvent`/`reactiveValues` it works as well (and maybe you need the `reactiveValues` for more complex architectures)

Comment: @starja you are right, that in general `reactive` / `eventReactive` should be used rather than `observe` / `observeEvent` (Future readers may find some info regarding this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53016404/advantages-of-reactive-vs-observe-vs-observeevent)). However, in this particular case I don't think using `eventReactive` is very convenient as we are dealing with a self-referencing reactive which, in contrast to `reactiveValues`, leads us to infinite recursion. But, maybe I'm missing something, so please feel free to give an example to show me how you'd solve this. Cheers

Comment: Hi, can you take a look on this and help me out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71301712/shiny-observeevent-and-actionbutton-adding-a-column-to-table