# read_xlsx not able to access tmp path of Shiny upload

Tags: r, shiny, readxl

I am trying to write a Shiny App which takes multiple xlsx files as input, processes them and offers to download a summary file afterwards. In a first step, I construct a dummy DF to append the the files to. Please note that this is my first experience with Shiny apps.

Unfortunately the app crashes directly after uploading the files. It seems `read_xlsx` is not able to work with the path of the tmp files uploaded. Following warning/error is received when running the app:

```
Warnung in read_fun(path = enc2native(normalizePath(path)), sheet_i = sheet, 
  NAs durch Umwandlung erzeugt
Warnung: Error in :: NA/NaN Argument
```

In the example code at the end (example is design to only upload 1 file), I added some print statements to debug the warnings. See the output below. What catches my eye is the `character(0)` result of the third print statement, which correlates to the warning of the app. I am pretty sure I am missing something very basic here, but what is it? Is this related to environments as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53016404/advantages-of-reactive-vs-observe-vs-observeevent)?

```
[1] "C:\\Users\\userxyz\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpE5aM7A/0448481d282a5ba2c08583e0/0.xlsx"
[1] 25
character(0)
character(0)
[1] "B15:Z16"
```

minimal example:

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)

calc <- function(tmp_files, num_of_cols) {

    print(tmp_files)
    print(num_of_cols)
    
    files <- list.files(enc2native(normalizePath(tmp_files)), full.names = T)
    files2 <- list.files(tmp_files, full.names = T)
    print(files)
    print(files2

    cell_range <- paste0("B15:", toupper(letters[num_of_cols+1]), "16")
    
    print(cell_range)
    
    cols <- read_xlsx(tmp_files, range = cell_range, col_names = letters[1:cell_range]) %>%
        mutate_all(str_replace_na, replacement = "") %>%
        transmute_all(str_c, collapse = "") %>%
        slice(-1) %>%
        as.character()

}

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            fileInput("upload", "Upload Files",
                      multiple = TRUE),
            numericInput(inputId = "num_of_cols",
                      label = "Specify number of Columns",
                      value = 0),
            actionButton(inputId = "gobutton", "GO!"),
            downloadButton("downloadbutton", "Download Results")
        ),
        mainPanel(
            tableOutput("upload_overview")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    output$upload_overview <- renderTable(input$upload$datapath)
    
    observeEvent(
        input$gobutton, {
        data <- calc(input$upload$datapath, input$num_of_cols)
    })

    output$downloadbutton <- downloadHandler(
        filename = "table.xlsx",
        content = function(file) {write_xlsx(data, path = file)}
    )
        
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Your issue is in the `calc()` function.  `col_names = letters[1:cell_range]` is improperly defined as `cell_range` is not a number, but `B15:C16` when 2 col are selected.  The error you are noticing is coming from this statement.

Comment: Perhaps you should use `col_names = letters[1:num_of_cols]`

Comment: Well silly me, sometimes one should just head for weekend... Thank you guys, your answers did the trick, data is getting imported now.