# How to save the inputs, inside Data Frame which is inside the list?

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I tried to keep reprex as simple as possible.

I want to save with the **ADD** button currently chosen inputs, inside Data Frame *(selected by index passed by userId input)*, which is inside the list, and later on use this Data Frame to render a table (in the final app make a plot).

Here I figured out, how to save values inside the data frame. *(not data frame inside a list)*
[How to save input to data frame, and use it later in Shiny?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71881012/how-to-save-input-to-data-frame-and-use-it-later-in-shiny?noredirect=1#comment127022209_71881012)

Now **Add** button returns this:
*Warning: Error in choosen_user: unused argument (rbind(choosen_user(), new_day_rate()))* <- this is propably because I used `reactive()` not `reactiveVal()`, **but** with `reactiveVal()` there is this error:

*Warning: Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext: Operation not allowed without an active reactive context.
You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive consumer.*

```
library(shiny)

# Saved_users_list normally came from external file
saved_users_list <- list(data.frame(date = c(as.Date("2022-04-18"),
                                       as.Date("2022-04-19")),
                              rate = c(8,1),
                              day_comment = c("Found a gf",
                                              "Broke my arm")),
                   data.frame(date = c(as.Date("2022-04-18"),
                                       as.Date("2022-04-19")),
                              rate = c(10,1),
                              day_comment = c("Found a job",
                                              "They fired me")))


ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("userId", "userId", choices = c(1:2)),
      sliderInput("day_rate", "Rate your day", min = 0, max = 10, value = 5, step = 0.5),
      dateInput("date", "Pick a date"),
      textAreaInput("comment", "Comment", placeholder = "Add a description (OPTIONAL)"),
      actionButton("add", "Add"),
      actionButton("test", "Test values") # Button to test inputs values
      ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("test_table")
    )
    )
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  users_list <- reactiveVal(saved_users_list)
  selected_user <- reactive(as.numeric(input$userId))
  
  output$test_table <- renderTable({
    users_list()[selected_user()]
  })
  
    new_day_rate <- reactive(list(data.frame(date = input$date,
                                             rate = input$day_rate,
                                             day_comment = input$comment)))
    
    choosen_user <- reactive(users_list()[[selected_user()]])
    
    # Button to add values to the data frame inside users_list
    observeEvent(input$add, {
    # users_list()[[selected_user()]]  <- rbind(users_list()[[selected_user()]], as.data.frame(new_day_rate())) # Error in <-: invalid (NULL) left side of assignment

    choosen_user(rbind(choosen_user(), new_day_rate())) # Here I tried to implement a solution from linked question 
  })
  
  # Button to test inputs values
  observeEvent(input$test, {
    message("userId: ", input$userId, " ", class(input$userId))
    message("selected_user(): ", selected_user())
    message("new_day_rate(): ", new_day_rate())
    message("str(new_day_rate()): ", str(new_day_rate()))
    message("users_list()[[selected_user()]]: ",users_list()[[selected_user()]])
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're after `reactiveValues`?  Something like:

```r
library(shiny)

# Saved_users_list normally came from external file
saved_users_list <- list(
  data.frame(
    date = c(as.Date("2022-04-18"), as.Date("2022-04-19")),
    rate = c(8,1),
    day_comment = c("Found a gf", "Broke my arm")
  ),
  data.frame(
    date = c(as.Date("2022-04-18"), as.Date("2022-04-19")),
    rate = c(10,1),
    day_comment = c("Found a job", "They fired me")
  )
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("userId", "userId", choices = c(1:2)),
      sliderInput("day_rate", "Rate your day", min = 0, max = 10, value = 5, step = 0.5),
      dateInput("date", "Pick a date"),
      textAreaInput("comment", "Comment", placeholder = "Add a description (OPTIONAL)"),
      actionButton("add", "Add"),
      actionButton("test", "Test values") # Button to test inputs values
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("test_table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  cache <- reactiveValues(saved_users = saved_users_list)
  selected_user <- reactive(as.numeric(input$userId))

  output$test_table <- renderTable({
    cache$saved_users[selected_user()]
  })

  new_day_rate <- reactive(
    data.frame(
      date = as.Date(input$date),
      rate = input$day_rate,
      day_comment = input$comment
    )
  )

  observeEvent(input$add, {
    cache$saved_users[[selected_user()]] <- rbind(
      cache$saved_users[[selected_user()]], new_day_rate()
    )
  })

  observeEvent(input$test, {
    message("userId: ", input$userId, " ", class(input$userId))
    message("selected_user(): ", selected_user())
    message("new_day_rate(): ", new_day_rate())
    message("str(new_day_rate()): ", str(new_day_rate()))
    message("users_list()[[selected_user()]]: ", cache$saved_users[[selected_user()]])
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```